# Store Api data to a class react native

Tags: react-native

I am getting data from API.I need to push that data to a class.Below is my basic class structure:

Attendance.js

```
class Attendance{
constructor(SessionDate,SubjectName,Att){
  this.SessionDate = SessionDate;
  this.SubjectName = SessionDate+'-'+SubjectName;
  this.Att = Att;
  
}
}

export default Attendance ;
```

Here is my Action class:

attendance.js

```
import Attendance from "../../models/Attendance";
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

export const SET_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE = 'SET_SET_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE';

export const fetchStudentAttendance = (newDate) => {
return async (dispatch,getState) =>{
  const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
  const transformedData = JSON.parse(userData);
  const { token } = transformedData;

 const Date = newDate;
  try{const response = await fetch(
      `http://........./api/stud/Get_Stud_Attendance_Details?Date=${Date}`,
      {
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization':token
      },
    }
    );


   const resData = await response.json();
   console.log(resData);

   const loadedStudentAtt = [];

   loadedStudentAtt.push(new Attendance(
   resData["WeeklyAttendanceList"].SessionDate,
   resData["WeeklyAttendanceList"].SubjectAbbr,
   resData["WeeklyAttendanceList"].Att,
   ));

   console.log(loadedStudentAtt);

   dispatch({type: SET_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE,studentattendance:loadedStudentAtt});
   }
   catch(err){
   console.log(err);
   throw err;

   };
   };
   };
```

Below is the sample API data:

```
Object {
"Error": null,
"Response": null,
"StartDate": "2020-02-04T00:00:00",
"StudentAttendancePercentList": Array [],
"Successful": true,
"WeeklyAttendanceList": Array [
Object {
  "Att": "1",
  "SessionDate": "28 Jan 2020",
  "SessionDayName": "",
  "SessionNo": 1,
  "SessionTiming": "09:15 - 10:30",
  "SubjectAbbr": "Subject1",
},
Object {
  "Att": "0",
  "SessionDate": "28 Jan 2020",
  "SessionDayName": "",
  "SessionNo": 1,
  "SessionTiming": "09:15 - 10:30",
  "SubjectAbbr": "Subject2",
},
],
}
```

The array that I am getting in console.log() is as below:

```
Array [
Attendance {
"Att": undefined,
"SessionDate": undefined,
"SubjectName": "undefined-undefined",
```

},
]

Can you please tell am I pushing the data correctly to the class?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WeeklyAttendanceList is Array of Objects. So you have to iterate over it and push that data into loadedStudentAtt.

```
const resData = await response.json();
console.log(resData);

const WeeklyAttendanceList = resData.WeeklyAttendanceList;

const loadedStudentAtt = [];

WeeklyAttendanceList.forEach(item => {
    loadedStudentAtt.push(new Attendance(
   item.SessionDate,
   item.SubjectAbbr,
   item.Att,
   ))
})

console.log(loadedStudentAtt);
```

Comment: I could push data to the class using the above code.Thanks a lot Ferin Patel.